# harvesting data via websites drop down data in R

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to get all data from all zip codes in pgform 2. How can I do that?

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://wilottery.com/where-to-buy"
pgsession <- html_session(url)
pgform <-html_form(pgsession)[[2]]

pgform$fields[[1]]$name <- "zip"
pgform$fields[[2]]$name <- "cities"


filled_form <- set_values(form = pgform,
                          zip = "All zipcodes")



d <- submit_form(session=pgsession, form=filled_form)

y <- d %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[2]] %>%
  html_table(header=TRUE)
```

From this I am expecting to harvest all the possible data from all wisconsin's zip codes, irrespective of its cities.

UPDATE:
Thanks QHarr for your help!

I figured it out. After some adjustments to your code I have following as a final table.

```
get_results <- function(zip){
  r <- POST('https://wilottery.com/where-to-buy', 
            add_headers(headers = c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')),
            body = list('action'='search', zip = zip))
  results <- jsonlite::parse_json(read_html(r)%>%html_node('p')%>%html_text())
  df.results <- do.call(rbind, do.call(rbind, results))
  return(df.results)
}

zips <- read_html('https://wilottery.com/where-to-buy') %>%
  html_nodes('#zip [value]') %>%
  html_attr('value')

df <- as.data.frame(get_results(zips[1]))

for(zip in 1:length(zips)){
  t <- as.data.frame(get_results(zips[zip]))
  df <- rbind(t, df)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page does POST requests using the zip code to return html which containg json data inside a p tag. You can first collect the dropdown value attributes which are the zip codes; then issue post requests and parse out json from html and pass to jsonlite. Do then whatever you need to with results

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)


get_results <- function(zip_code){
  r <- POST('https://wilottery.com/where-to-buy', 
            add_headers(headers = c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')),
            body = list('action'='search', 'zip' = zip_code))
  results <- jsonlite::parse_json(read_html(r)%>%html_node('p')%>%html_text())
  return(results)
}

zips <- read_html('https://wilottery.com/where-to-buy') %>%
          html_nodes('#zip [value]') %>%
          html_attr('value')

for(zip_code in zips){
  print(get_results(zip))
  break #delete me later and decide what to do with results
}
```

Comment: Thanks Qharr, what if i want to combine all data from zipcodes into one dataframe

Comment: Do they all have the same number of columns? If so you could bind them for example.

Comment: df <- as.data.frame(get_results(zip))

for(zip_code in zips){
  t <- as.data.frame(get_results(zip))
  print(t)
  df <- rbind(t, df)
  
}

Comment: I will look into this tomorrow/saturday.